# Why does water surface in an accelerating cart seek level?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

This is from lecture 8 of MIT OpenCourseWare's 2.003SC Engineering Dynamics (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNCBDrnT05E&t=3120s) from minute 52:00 to 56:48.

The situation is there is a cart accelerating down a slope. As the cart accelerates down, the water level in the cart adjusts to be parallel to the slope. The professor explained that if one includes the fictious force due to cart accelerating in to the free body diagram(show in dashed line), the forces in the x-direction (parallel to the slope) cancel out, so the water only experiences the force in y-direction (perpendicular to the slope) and it adjusts the surface to be perpendicular to the force it feels. However, I am not clear with this explanation, as it is obvious that the forces in y-direction also cancel out, so why would the water experiences force in the y-direction only and not in the x-direction?.

[image]

Moreover, in the case that the cart accelerates on a flat surface, the forces (including the fictitious force) also cancel out in every direction, why does the water still pile up at the back of the cart?

Comment: For a flat surface the force in x direction is zero. I assume the car only experiences  gravitational froce.

Comment: @Martin But it also experiences normal force in y-direction, which cancels the gravitaional force. Shouldn't the net force in y-direction be zero as well?